# What does it mean to pray in Jesus' Name?

Tags: exegesis, prayer, gospels, gospel-of-john, name-of-jesus

A few times in the book of John, Jesus instructs us to pray "in His Name".  What does this mean?  How do we know if we are praying in His name?  How would we not be praying in His name?

I don't believe this is using "In Jesus' Name, Amen" as the closing line of our prayers.

> Whatever you ask **in my name**, this I will do, that the Father may
>   be glorified in the Son.  If you ask me anything **in my name**, I
>   will do it.  John 14:13-14 ESV
>
> You did not choose me, but I chose you and appointed you that you
>   should go and bear fruit and that your fruit should abide, so that
>   whatever you ask the Father in my name, he may give it to you.  John
>   15:16 ESV
>
> In that day you will ask nothing of me. Truly, truly, I say to you,
>   whatever you ask of the Father **in my name**, he will give it to you.
>   Until now you have asked nothing **in my name**. Ask, and you will
>   receive, that your joy may be full.  "I have said these things to you
>   in figures of speech. The hour is coming when I will no longer speak
>   to you in figures of speech but will tell you plainly about the
>   Father. In that day you will ask **in my name**, and I do not say to
>   you that I will ask the Father on your behalf; for the Father himself
>   loves you, because you have loved me and have believed that I came
>   from God.  John 16:23-27 ESV

Interestingly, there are other things that refer to "in Jesus' name':

> Whoever receives one such child in my name receives me  Matthew 18:5
>   ESV
>
> For where two or three are gathered in my name, there am I among them.
>   Matthew 18:20 ESV
>
> Many will come in my name, saying, 'I am he!' and they will lead many
>   astray.  Mark 13:6 ESV

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be answered by answering a more general question: what does "in someone's (anyone's) name" mean?  It means to act by proxy, on the authority of something or someone greater than yourself. It's a concept that our culture has kind of lost, though it still exists as a storytelling trope.  When a medieval herald reads a proclamation "in the name of the king," or a cop yells at a fleeing thief to "stop in the name of the law!" this is what they mean.  It's a convenient shorthand for "I'm not just saying this of myself; I'm speaking with the authority of a higher power."

So how does this apply to acting (and praying) in the name of Christ?  It means to act in his place.  To pray in the name of Jesus is to pray what Jesus would pray if he were in your position.  When we understand this in the context of Christ as the Perfect Man and our Exemplar, it means to pray for the right things, to seek the will of God and not our own desires.  And whatever we ask the Father in the name of Jesus Christ, that will be given to us.

Answer (score 1):

To ask "in His name" simply means "in" or "with" His authority....Jesus has given believers His spiritual "power of attorney" to use His authority....God only answer those who approach Him "in" or "with" the consent, or "authority" of His Son. This is another reason Jesus said no one comes unto the Father except  by Him. All who believe in the substitutional death of Jesus receive four imputations: the Holy Spirit, eternal life, righteousness, and His (Jesus') authority! The apostle Paul said "these things we are to KNOW!"

Comment: A good answer, though I'd qualify that God does sometimes listen to prayers that aren't prayed in Jesus' name, such as the prayers of the OT saints. But as Christians we have a promise that God will always listen to our prayers.

Answer (score 0):

What does this mean? "When that time comes, you won't have to ask me about anything. I tell you for certain that the Father will give you whatever you ask for in my name?"

Based on my personal experience, I always remember what Luke wrote in the Bible : (1) God sent the angel Gabriel to Mary in Nazareth. The angel Gabriel told Mary : "You will have a son. HIS NAME WILL BE JESUS." (Luke 1: 31); (2)   Mary asked the angel Gabriel, "How can this happen? I am not married!" The angel answered, "THE HOLY SPIRIT will come down to you, and God's power will come over you. So your child will be called the HOLY SON OF GOD." (Luke 1:34-35). So ask something to the heavenly Father in Jesus' name means ask something to the heavenly Father in the name of Jesus, the Holy Spirit, the Holy Son of God; (3) John wrote : " 23 But a time is coming, and it is already here! Even now the true worshipers are being led by the Spirit to worship the Father according to the truth. These are the ones the Father is seeking to worship him. 24 God is Spirit, and those who worship God must be led by the Spirit to worship him according to the truth." (John 4:23-24).

Thank you, God bless you!

Comment: The only answer I see here is: "So ask something to the heavenly Father in Jesus' name means ask something to the heavenly Father in the name of Jesus, the Holy Spirit, the Holy Son of God." That says very little, and is almost tautological.

Answer (score 0):

Praying in Jesus’ name is praying for things that will honor and glorify Jesus.

Saying “in Jesus’ name” at the end of a prayer is not a magic formula. If what we ask for or say in prayer is not for God’s glory and according to His will, saying “in Jesus’ name” is meaningless. Genuinely praying in Jesus' name and for His glory is what is important, not attaching certain words to the end of a prayer. It is not the words in the prayer that matter, but the purpose behind the prayer. Praying for things that are in agreement with God’s will is the essence of praying in Jesus’ name.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: This appears to be taken from https://gotquestions.org/pray-Jesus-name.html. It's good to cite your sources :)

Answer (score 0):

Good responses! I'd like to add my Biblical Hebrew two cents, since Jesus and the apostles were raised expressing themselves in a Hebrew mindset. The word "name" (*SheM* in Hebrew) is derived from the verb *ShiYM* "to place" and carries the meaning of "position, rank, honor, fame, reputation and authority". It reminds me of Sceva's seven sons in Acts 19:15 who thought they could incant the name of Jesus though Paul but didn't have His authority. We have to be in the place of Jesus, as if crucified with him, dying to self, seeking no personal fame or honor. Our authority only exists as we proclaim as his representatives what He has given us to speak. When He is our all in all, we will have the faith to bind and release and move mountains, because it won't be **our** will that we pray for, but **His**.

Answer (score -2):

Be mindful that Jesus said "no one" comes unto the Father save through Him....that includes in prayer (John 16:23 & 24)....OT saints had direct contact with God, but not NT saints after Jesus came,....God'S presence was with OT saints in the Holy of Hollies, but not after Jesus came,.... God tore the veil of the temple to reveal that His presence was no longer with the Israelites, Jesus became the new way to approach God....Paul called Jesus the "living veil" to approach God....(Hebrews 10:19 & 20)....therefore without approaching God through the "living veil," (Jesus Christ), no one can reach God, not even in prayer! That's why we're to pray "in His name;" that is, with His authorization to do so!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange! Welcome to the site. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) This doesn't really answer the question. The OP clearly recognizes that prayer should be in Jesus' name, s/he is asking what this means specifically, which you have not explained.