# Should we pray for someone's salvation?

Tags: soteriology

Today a Pastor on a local TV (in India) was preaching that we need not pray for someone's salvation. Salvation is something that belongs to God and His Plans. He also said that nowhere in the New testament are believers requested to pray for sinners or to ask God for a non-believer's salvation.

He said the plan of salvation by God is already fulfilled, and we only preach the Gospel and live a model life for unsaved people to come to our Lord.

Revealtion 19:1 says,

> 19 After these things I heard a loud voice of a great multitude in heaven, saying, “Alleluia! Salvation and glory and honor and power belong to the Lord.

If salvation belongs to the Lord, praying for someone's salvation would become absurd, correct?

*PS: I found another question  [Praying for someone's salvation. Is there a point?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/praying-for-someones-salvation-is-there-a-point) but that was asked in a bit different approach. If this question still seems irrelevant, kindly close it or merge it. Thanks.*

Comment: Depends on how hard line Calvinist you are. If you believe in strict predestination, then it is a (notice not 'the') logical conclusion to say you don't need to pray for their salvation, because God will effect his desire in any event. That said, svn a Calvinst can be grateful for the opportunity to participate in Gods work by bringing the matter up to the Father in obedience.

Comment: I agree with Jas31, additionally, without a particular scope/perspective, this question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Please bring this old question into current site guidelines. Thanks. Resource for your convenience: [Question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac)

Comment: I would suggest two questions arising from this:  What is the reasoning behind 1) PRAYING for someone's salvation and 2) NOT praying for someone's salvation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make an assertion that Christians should not do something, one must appeal to an authoritative source, most likely the Bible.  Nowhere in the Bible are we commanded *not* to pray for the salvation of unbelievers, and that is quite problematic to the argument.  Indeed, if we are not supposed to do something, would God not have mentioned it somewhere instead of leaving it up to us to figure out based on obscure logic?

In reality, the apostle Paul gives us an example for us to pray that others may be saved.  He specifically prays for Jewish unbelievers, and his prayer is specifically for their salvation.  While he does not specifically request others to do so, it would be quite a stretch to assert that this was only something Paul did that no one else was supposed to do.

> Brothers, my heart's desire and prayer to God for them is that they
>   may be saved.  Romans 10:1 ESV

Indeed, if God answers prayer, it would be difficult to find something to pray for in which He is more glorified than in someone responding to Jesus in faith.

Salvation does, indeed, come from God.  It is He who does the saving, so it's His salvation in that it comes from Him.  Yet, it is our salvation in that we are the ones saved by it.

Answer (score 7):

I find that I pray for others salvation a lot but its not a "please Lord save this sinner" type thing as it is an active prayer. I pray that their heart may be softened so that the gospel can take root in their heart and change them. I ask if there is anything that I can do to help that process and I pray for them to find comfort in trials and to know that that comfort is coming from God.

That's my take on praying for someones salvation and I think that yes its something we all should be doing. However your question is a little broad and you are going to get several different answers depending on the denomination that is answering.

As for my reasons for answering the way I did I think this scripture can help:

> (KJV) Ephesians 6:17-18 And take the helmet of salvation, and the sword of the Spirit, which is the word of God: 18) Praying always with all prayer and supplication in the Spirit, and watching thereunto with all perseverance and supplication for all saints;

Paul describes something active in taking the *helmet of salvation* and then in watching in prayer over all the saints.

Also as @Affable Geek said it depends on what your thought process is on salvation. Some believe that it is solely up to the Lord. Others believe that it takes faith alone, and yet others believe that it takes faith and works to obtain salvation. So whether its appropriate for you to pray for someones salvation depends on where you fall in those three main groups. (And that does not even begin to cover all the different thoughts on how one obtains or is given salvation).

Answer (score 2):

The bible is the best authority, as always, I Tim.2:1-5;

> 1"First of all, then, I urge that entreaties and prayers, petitions
>   and thanksgivings, be made on behalf of *all men*, 2for kings and all
>   who are in authority, so that we may lead a tranquil and quiet life in
>   all godliness and dignity. 3This is good and acceptable in the sight
>   of God our Savior, 4who desires *all men* to be saved and to come to
>   the knowledge of the truth. 5For there is one God, and one mediator
>   also between God and men, the man Christ Jesus, 6who gave Himself as a
>   ransom *for all*, the testimony given at the proper time"  1 Timothy 2:1-5
>
> I Tim. 4:10 - "For it is for this we labor and strive, because we have
>   fixed our hope on the living God, who is *the Savior of all men*,
>   especially of believers."

I chose these verses from I Timothy from among many such verses found in the bible (for example II Pet.3:9c - "not wishing that any should perish' etc.) to illustrate that it is God's will of desire that all men have opportunity for salvation.

I am aware that strong Calvinist interpret these and like verses to apply only to the elect. I do not believe the Greek supports the translation; ex. in Timothy as "All types or categories of men" nor in II Pet. "Not willing that any of us-ward (i.e. believers) should perish." Therefore I believe it is clearly proper to pray for the salvation of the unsaved.

Answer (score 1):

I see prayer as an act of obedience. Prayer changes our hearts to be in line with God's will as we commune with Him in it. If I pray for someone it does not mean God will force salvation upon them because that would violate their free will. God desires but does not force all to be saved. If someone's salvation depended upon my prayers then it is by me and not by Christ. If I pray for someone, and my heart is open to what the Holy Spirit would have me preach and live the Gospel before them, then the transforming power of God being demonstrated to them by my life may convince them of the truth. We are commanded to preach, teach, make disciples, forgive sins; we are to be God's hands and ambassadors in this world. If I don't pray for their salvation, but pray that God would open my mind and the minds of other saints in a way that would allow the Gospel to be preached with authoritative it will be equally effective.
**Prayer for Spiritual Insight**
***Ephesians 1: 
15 This is why, since I heard about your faith in the Lord Jesus and your love for all the saints, 16 I never stop giving thanks for you as I remember you in my prayers. 17 I pray that the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the glorious Father, would give you a spirit of wisdom and revelation in the knowledge of Him. 18 I pray that the perception of your mind may be enlightened so you may know what is the hope of His calling, what are the glorious riches of His inheritance among the saints, 19 and what is the immeasurable greatness of His power to us who believe, according to the working of His vast strength.***

**Romans 10:17 *So then faith comes by hearing, and hearing by the word of God.***

**Mark 15 *Then He said to them, “Go into all the world and preach the gospel to the whole creation. 16 Whoever believes and is baptized will be saved, but whoever does not believe will be condemned.***

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for your contribution and we hope you keep posting. As a general priniciple, try and answer in a way that faithfully represents a particular identifiable Christian (denominational or doctrinal) perspective and doesn't come across as just your own opinion.  Further site guidelines are available in our [help centre](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help). Peace.

Comment: Christian, SBC, Soul competency, Inductive exegetical Bible   by the Holy Spirit  and Premillennial Dispensational. Calvinism and Arminianism are terms the disciples would not be familiar with and even though I lean towards reformed theology they are still all doctrines of man.

Comment: If you want to start your own forum and post your content there, then you're free to do it according to how you see fit; but if you're posting on this site, you'll need to understand it's guidelines and adhere to them.

Comment: SBC is the largest protestant denomination, of which I am a teacher and doctrine defender. I do not understand which of your guidelines I have violated. Be more specific.

Comment: If you had 'violated' anything, I would not have upvoted you and given you general advice for future posting - I would have addressed a specific issue with your post. However, the amount of time you use 'I' in your answer, and the lack of citations or references to particular perspectives *do* give the *impression* that the post is your *personal* opinion. Please read our meta post [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) for further clarification of site expectations for answers.

Answer (score 0):

To put in another perspective, it is traditional for Orthodox Christians to pray for the salvation of not only other living people, but also for the dead. Note that when we pray for 'salvation, visitation and continuance in all good things' as the common prayer states, we do not make a distinction between believers and non believers, and ultimately, no distinction between the living and the dead. Although there is an important point here as to why this prayer is generally first towards the living - those who are glorified do not need to be prayed for, but instead are asked to entreat God for those of us who struggle. But then what that means is those people are those who did not taste of death; they, like the Thief on the cross were 'that day with Him in Paradise' to paraphrase.

To 'undigress', also from our perspective we can take note of two stark facts:

1. God wills that all men be saved. Who can countervail his will?
2. Not all men end up being saved. We know of at least Judas, and according to our tradition, Arius as well.

Given this, we should say that our praying for the salvation of people is not asking God to save them - he already has. Instead, we are asking him to help incline their heart toward him to accept the gift he freely gives. Given this, why would you not pray for their salvation? Do you not want to live with them in Eternity? Do you not want to see them glorified and at perfect peace?

I know some people I'd rather not be around. But to not want good things for them, especially the Good Things, is certainly lacking in Charity. Let a person decide for themselves where they stand on this.